# RadcomboBox css help needed

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik

I am trying to change the font color on disabled radcombobox control. Any idea what I may be doing wrong in the code below for the font color not to work?

```
.RadComboBox_Web20 .rcbDisabled .rcbInputCell input,
.RadComboBox_Web20 .rcbDisabled .rcbInputCell .rcbItem,
.RadComboBox_Web20 .rcbDisabled .rcbInputCell .rcbInput,
.RadComboBoxDropDown_Web20 .rcbDisabled .rcbInputCell input,
.RadComboBoxDropDown_Web20 .rcbDisabled .rcbInputCell .rcbItem, 
.RadComboBoxDropDown_Web20 .rcbDisabled .rcbInputCell .rcbInput,
.RadComboBoxDropDown_Web20 .rcbDisabled
{
    background-color: #808080;
    color: #0000FF;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: The font color is the only thing not working?  Can you include your markup as well?

Comment: <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlStatus"  runat="server" Width="200" Enabled="false">
                                            </telerik:RadComboBox>

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Web20 skin? Using the suffix makes these styles valid only for this skin.

Also, the `rcbInput` is actually the `input` element, and the `rcbItem` elements are not within the `rcbInputCell`. That said, the following CSS should work:

```
div.RadComboBox .rcbDisabled,
div.RadComboBox .rcbDisabled .rcbInputCell .rcbInput
{
    background-color: #808080;
    color: #0000FF;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: none;
}
```

I don't get the usage of background-image, though - what are you trying to achieve (apart from changing the font-color)?